# WCF 4.5 ChannelFactory Caching

Tags: c#, wcf, caching, channelfactory

I have a FactoryClass that creates and caches the ChannelFactory. Before .Net framework 4.5, we used to do caching manually using Dictionary.

In .Net Framework 4.5 Microsoft started providing caching and we implemented the same. But is there a way we can know whether the channelfactory is cached or not?

Below is our code:

```
public T CreateChannel<T>()
{
    ClientBase<IClientChannel>.CacheSetting = CacheSetting.AlwaysOn;
    ChannelFactory<T> factory = new ChannelFactory<T>("*", new EndpointAddress("SomeUrl"));
    return factory.CreateChannel();
}
```

Comment: Not sure if question is valid or not, because further digging/reading on msdn says, "WCF can cache channel factories when you are using a WCF client proxy.". Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh314046(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think that when you create a `ChannelFactory` manually (via `new ChannelFactory<T>(...`), it is not cached. It is only cached when it is created implicitly when you instantiate a `ClientBase<T>` derived class.